# Swift Combine Cancel Publishers Without AnyCancellable

Tags: ios, swift, combine, publisher, anycancellable

I have my networking library based on Combine. Anywhere in my app I can make a request and the networking library returns a publisher, it doesn't have access to the AnyCancellable that is created that actually triggers the pipeline. What I need is the ability to cancel all network requests when the use logs out. Is there a way to cancel Combine pipelines from the publisher not the AnyCancellable.

Here is an example:

```
    var subscribers = [AnyCancellable]()
    let url = URL(string:"https://www.apeth.com/pep/manny.jpg")!
    let request: AnyPublisher<UIImage, URLError> = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0.data) }
        .share()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    request
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
            print("subscription2 completed")
        }, receiveValue: { image in
            print("subscription1 value: \(image.scale)")
        })
        .store(in: &subscribers)
    
    // request.cancel()
```

I would like to call something like request.cancel() on the publisher so that the receiveValue is never triggered.

Comment: Look into the new Concurrency or async/await this sounds like a good use case

Comment: "Here is an example" When the user logs out, simply destroy the object in which that code appears. The pipelines stored in `subscribers` will all be cancelled.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "destroy the object in which that code appears". What am I destroying? Let's say a View Controller has the sink and holds onto the AnyCancellable. My Network API doesn't know anything about the View Controller, but I do have a reference to the Publisher that was returned in the Network API. I need my Network API to be able to cancel anything listening to the publishers it created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need is the ability to cancel all network requests when the use logs out.

I suggest you setup a publisher that emits when the user logs out. Then in your API system, you can use `prefix(untilOutputFrom: logoutPublisher)`.

That way, all your network requests will cancel when the logoutPublisher emits.

Comment: There is no operator `prefix(untilOutputFrom:)`?

Comment: Yes there is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/prefix(untiloutputfrom:)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I knew about the drop variant but not the prefix variant.

Answer (score -1):

The `sink` method returns a single `AnyCancellable` that you can store in
a dedicated property for the request instead of storing the cancellable in the array.

When you need to cancel the subscription, just deinitialize the cancellable, because, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable) "An `AnyCancellable` instance automatically calls `cancel()` when deinitialized."

```swift
private var requestCancellable: AnyCancellable?

func setUpSubscription() {
    requestCancellable = request
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
            print("subscription2 completed")
        }, receiveValue: { image in
            print("subscription1 value: \(image.scale)")
        })
}

func cancelSubscription() {
    requestCancellable = nil
}
```